# how to write sub query not null as join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select EmpName, EmpCode
from employees
where EmpBrnID = 461 and EmpIsActive =1 
  and EmpCode not in (select EmpCode from reports
                      where BranchID = 461 and DAYOFWEEK(InTime)!= 1
                        and InTime BETWEEN  '2017-01-31'- INTERVAL 6 DAY AND '2017-01-31');
```

how can i write this as join.

Comment: Why would you? But anyway, you are looking for an **anti join**.

Comment: @Ramanil You don't need a `JOIN` here. You want data from only one table then why would you join it with some other table?

Comment: sub query takes more time to get result so i want to write join.how to get data fast with sub query.@ Jibin Balachandran

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that?

```
SELECT
  empname
, empcode
FROM employees    e
LEFT JOIN reports r
  ON e.empbrnid=r.branchid
WHERE e.empbrnid=461
  AND DAYOFWEEK(intime)!=1
  AND InTime BETWEEN  '2017-01-31'- INTERVAL 6 DAY AND '2017-01-31')
  AND r.branchid IS NULL
;
```

So it's a left join where the right table's columns are NULL.

Cheers  -

Marco the Sane

Answer (score 0):

```
select EmpName, EmpCode
from employees
left join reports on reports.EmpCode = employees.EmpCode
    and BranchID = 461 and DAYOFWEEK(InTime)!= 1
                        and InTime BETWEEN  '2017-01-31'- INTERVAL 6 DAY AND '2017-01-31'
where EmpBrnID = 461 and EmpIsActive =1 
    and reports.EmpCode IS NULL
```